# Handle creation of similar items in one controller

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I make rest-api to online shop and I have a base product class, which have Name, Description, CreatedAt and Id fields. And there could potentially be about ten types of products in this store, the creation of which I would like to combine into one controller, if possible.

I try to make a one controller to one type, but i think i can simplify it.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateProduct(CreateProductDto dto)
{
    var newProduct = await _productService.CreateProduct(dto);
    return CreatedAtRoute(GetByIdRouteName, new { newProduct.Id }, newProduct);
}
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateProduct(CreateDollBoxDto dto)
{
    var newProduct = await _productService.CreateDollbox(dto);
    return CreatedAtRoute(GetByIdRouteName, new { newProduct.Id }, newProduct);
}
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateProduct(CreateChocoboxDto dto)
{
    var newProduct = await _productService.CreateChocobox(dto);
    return CreatedAtRoute(GetByIdRouteName, new { newProduct.Id }, newProduct);
}
```

Also I try to create an interface and cast "object" type to interface, but it doesn't work.
I think that factory-method can be useful in this case, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the difference between those DTO's? `CreateDollBoxDto`, `CreateChocoboxDto` and so on...

If they all have the same fields (Name, Description, CreatedAt and Id) you can use a single DTO and a single endpoint in your controller. You could add a `Type` field to specify what kind of product it is. This will scale much better, you will be able to handle new types of products without modifying and redeploying your server code.

Comment: All types of product have some unique fiels, f.e. CreateDollBoxDto has a "Name", "Description", "CreatedAd", "Id" like the Product and "Color" and "Size" only for this type.

Comment: In that case I'd say it's fine to have one endpoint for each type of product.